# C# template type inheritance

Tags: c#, inheritance, templates, types

I want to create a template class in C#, for example:

```
public class Foo<T>
```

where T must inherit from a known class.

I cant seem to find the syntax for that.

Thanks, Malki.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In .NET the term `generic class` is used instead of `template class`. And what you are trying to do is called [generic constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx):

```
public class Foo<T> where T : KnownClass
{

}
```